Calculate Year-over-Year Difference with User-Selected Reference and Comparison Years Using Slicers
"How can I create a measure in Power BI to calculate the difference (%) between two selected years, where the user can choose both the reference year and the comparison year from slicers on the same report page?"
I’ve created two slicers in Power BI: one for the reference year and another for the comparison year. I’m using the SELECTEDVALUE function to capture the years chosen by the user, and I’ve written a measure to calculate the difference between the values for each selected year.
Change in % 2 = 
VAR YearReference = SELECTEDVALUE('Dates'[Years])
VAR YearCompared = SELECTEDVALUE('Dates'[Years])
VAR ReferenceValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('GNA (2)'[Value (TEU)]), 
        'GNA (2)'[Year] = YearReference
    )
VAR ComparedValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('GNA(2)'[Value (TEU)]), 
        'GNA(2)'[Year] = YearCompared
    )
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(ReferenceValue) || ISBLANK(ComparedValue),
    BLANK(),
    DIVIDE((ComparedValue - ReferenceValue), ReferenceValue, 0) * 100
)


Can you share your model ? and some input data ?
